# Write application logs in Google App Engine with Python3?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, google-cloud-platform, cloud

In an effort to trace problems, my Python application needs to write logfiles. The application is supposed to migrate from Python2 to Python3, that is also supported on GCP as of recently. Google offers documentation for how to write application logs here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging#standard_environment_logs

Summarizing the above documentation, the application is only supposed to write to stdout/stderr, which GAE would collect.

Until now, the previous application does not appear. Following the above documentation I tried writing to stdout.

```
def some_func():                                                               
  """                                                                          
  Write an application log  
  """                                                                          
  print("(empty payload)")                                                            
  return make_response("OK", 200)
```

The expected result is I would find "(empty payload)" in the logfile.

However, I cannot find it. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what runtime you're trying to use? Is it  Flex or Second-Generation Standard (3.7?)

Comment: It's the 2nd Generation Standard Runtime

Comment: The corresponding page for the 2nd gen runtime is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs)

Comment: if I deploy the [hellowoldl quickstart for python3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart) and I add a `print` statement under the single handler there, the output of this `print` statement can be [found in the logs](https://imgur.com/a/ZvXSJ6w). I'm not getting what's not working correctly here. Can you provide contents of your `app.yaml` and the full contents of the code sample (with sensitive data redacted of course)

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, this was a stupid question. The content I tried to find in the log was base64 encoded, which was the reason I couldn't find it.